# Bash script to edit .ics files

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, menu, calendar

I would like to create a bash script to choose from .ics files in a folder then do a 'find and replace' within that selected file, then save and rename that file. I have cobbled together some things from searches, but don't know enough about what I'm doing to make it all work...

Here is what I have for a menu:

```
    #!/bin/bash

echo "The following `*.ics` files were found; select one:"

# set the prompt used by select, replacing "#?"
PS3="Use number to select a file or 'stop' to cancel: "

# allow the user to choose a file
select filename in *.ics
do
# leave the loop if the user says 'stop'
if [[ "$REPLY" == stop ]]; then break; fi

# complain if no file was selected, and loop to ask again
if [[ "$filename" == "" ]]
then
    echo "'$REPLY' is not a valid number"
    continue
fi

# now we can use the selected file
echo "$filename installed"

# it'll ask for another unless we leave the loop
break
done
```

This is the code I currently use to edit the .ics files, but it changes ALL .ics files in the current directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

###Fixes all .ics files to give ALL DAY events rather than 0000-2359  
####All .ics files
FILES="*.ics"


# for loop read each file
for f in $FILES
do
INF="$f"

##Change DTSTART:[yyyymmddThhmmss] to DTSTART;VALUE=DATE...##

sed -i[org] 's/DTSTART:2016/DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:2016/g' $INF

sed -i[org] 's/T[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/ /g' $INF

###Remove DTEND:###
sed -i[org] 's/DTEND:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/ /g'$INF

done
```

How can I put this all together to achieve my goal??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe structure it using a `case` construct, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

echo 'The following `*.ics` files were found; select one:'

select f in *.ics "Quit"; do
  case $f in
    "Quit")
      echo "Quitting"
      break
      ;;
    *)
      if [ -z "$f" ]; then
        echo "Invalid menu selection"
      else
        echo "Doing something with $f"
      fi
      ;;
    esac
done
```

Change the `echo "Doing something with $f"` to do whatever you want with the selected file - if it's relatively complex, I'd suggest moving it to a shell function. Remember to quote it i.e. `"$f"` to prevent word splitting.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Unfortunately I know just enough to be dangerous ;)  Could you give an example of where to place my "sed" lines, or where I would place the "shell function"?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out.  Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash


shopt -s nullglob

echo 'The following `*.ics` files were found; select one:'

select f in *.ics "Quit"; do
  case $f in
    "Quit")
      echo "Quitting"
      break
      ;;
    *)
      if [ -z "$f" ]; then
        echo "Invalid menu selection"
      else
        echo "Creating all-day events in $f"
          ##Change DTSTART:[yyyymmddThhmmss] to DTSTART;VALUE=DATE...##
          sed -i.orig 's/DTSTART:2016/DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:2016/g' "$f"
          sed -i.orig 's/T[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/ /g' "$f"
          ###Remove DTEND:###
          sed -i.orig  's/DTEND:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/ /g' "$f"
      fi
      ;;
    esac
done
```

Is there a way to repeat the menu after either a valid or invalid response?  (Sorry, I'm a bit of a newbie at this bash stuff, trying to learn as I go.)